# How to use absolute path to import custom scss, when using react + webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack

Inside a scss file, I'm trying to import custom, widely used chunk of scss (in a React/SASS/Webpack stack).

So that I can use a shared mixin.

Let's say I'm creating an MyAdminButton and I want to import scss file that concerns all the buttons of the project. (It's custom scss, not vendor/external one).

It would look like this :

```
//this actually works but it is a code smell : what if the current file moves ?
@import "../../stylesheets/_common-btn-styles.scss";

.my-admin-btn {
    // here I can use a shared mixin defined in _common-btn-styles.scss
}
```

This sounds not good since if my scss file move, then everything is broken.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Because refactoring occurs quite frequently, espescially if I put the scss file next to my js file : put everything that relates to the same component in same folder is very useful.

Comment: I have both manual dirty-check and automated tests, but I'm looking for robustness here. I know I will move folder without any fear.

Comment: You can use the `-I` argument to specify an import path. See `man scss` for more information.

Comment: @Klaus huh? How do you use CLI arguments in code?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found. Actually you can configure sass-loader in webpack.config.json, as described here : https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader

Here is the relevant part :

```
sassLoader: {
   includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./some-folder")]
}
```

Comment: Where in the file did you place it? and did absolute path actually work?

Comment: how i understood, that i should create react app not with npx create-react-app, instead of i should install all packages manual, and set up custom webpack. Only in this case can use it ? Or of i have already created app with create-react-app, can i just create webpack.config.js and use it there ? will it attach to main file a webpack of default react file ? Thx

Comment: what would be an example of an absolute path in the actual scss file?

Answer (score 6):

If you use Create React App v3 which [allows absolute imports](https://dev.to/mr_frontend/absolute-imports-in-create-react-app-3ge8) you can use the tilde

```
@import "~theme/colors";
```

Comment: Works also for sass in Angular 11

Comment: Not a real solution unless you are starting a new project using specifically *CRA* (not recommended anymore).

Comment: @vsync CRA is indeed outdated, but it works with Next.js as well

Comment: This question is about Webpack and not a specific framework that does inaccessible magic (because it is a framework). People come here because they want to know how to configure their webpack (like me)

Answer (score 4):

You could add *stylesheets* to the Webpack modules with [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules)

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/stylesheets'),
    ],
  },
}
```

And sass-loader allows you to import *_common-btn-styles.scss* from the modules. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules

```
@import "~_common-btn-styles.scss";

.my-admin-btn {
  // Use the shared mixins
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Webpack 5

Configuration is different for webpack 5 as `includePaths` should be specified in the option `sassOptions`:

```
// Webpack config
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '<path to styles>')],
    },
  },
},
```

## Webpack 4

I had to do so more research to solve this issue using other answers so here is my working solution:

```
// Webpack config
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '<path to styles>')],
  },
},
```

Then in your `scss` file:

```
@import 'filename.scss'; // Imported from <path to styles> folder.

.style {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In react-scripts latest version you can add a **`.env`** file at the project root with the variable **`SASS_PATH=node_modules:src`**.

To specify more directories you can add them to SASS_PATH separated by a **`:`** like **`path1:path2:path3`**

[official doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 2):

If using the Dart Sass implementation with `sass-loader`, the options are slightly different.

[The options for `sassOptions` are here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/Options)

```js
sassOptions: {
...
  loadPaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/')],
}
```

Comment: Already mentioned (by multiple people) here, years before you answered

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NextJS there is a simple implementation. You can read the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#customizing-sass-options).

In my case, I am using Tailwindcss and SASS, and here are the configuration files and sass files.

```js
// next.config.js


const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  sassOptions: {
    // define the absolute path...
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
};
```

```
// styles/_components.sass

@import 'tailwindcss/components'

@layer components
  .flex-center
    @apply flex items-center justify-center
  .container
    @apply mx-auto px-3 max-w-xl sm:max-w-lg md:px-6 md:max-w-3xl


// styles/global.sass

@import 'tailwindcss/base'
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities'
@import 'components' // absolute import


// app/styles.module.sass

@import 'components' // absolute import

.header
  @apply container flex h-16 items-center justify-between sticky top-0
```

Comment: I figured, that if you are using _PostCSS_, _TailwindCSS_ etc. you don't need to define sassOptions. PostCSS will take care of the paths. For my case, I configured absolute URLs in **tsconfig.json**, and using the import from its absolute path like: `@import 'style/components'`