# How to use SCSS absolute import path in a React, Webpack, Typescript Project?

Tags: reactjs, sass, sass-loader, webpack-config

I have been trying to import SCSS files with an absolute path for 2 days now...

## My folder structure:

src
|--assets
|--|--styles
|--|--|--**_variables.scss**
|--UI
|--|--**Layout.module.scss**

I would like to import variables and functions from `_variables.scss` to `Layout.module.scss` using an absolute path to avoid my code from breaking when changing the folder structure.

I am using the live sass compiler extension in VS code which trows the error

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

when I try to import a scss file using an absolute path like `@import 'src/assets/styles/variables'` .

Relative paths work just fine

## I tried several things:

1. Using the sass-loader `includePaths` option and including the `src` folder
2. Using the webpack `module.resolve` object in the config file to add the src folder to the folder that will be searched when trying to import modules and then using the `~assets/styles/variables` path
3. Using webpack `module.alias` object in the webpack config file to define an alias for the `src` folder and then use it like so `Styles/variables`

I looked up a lot of similar problems but neither of the solutions would help solve my problem. I would appreciate any possible solution!

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/35937477/104380